# Corrupted USB drive, dd, gparted, fdisk not helps

Tags: linux, usb, partitioning, gparted

I have SanDisk Cruzer Glide 3.0 16G USB Drive. My computer can recognize the USB drive, such as VendorID, ProductID, USB drive brand and model. Here is the my tryings;

Writing zeroes with dd: While i start to write, writing zeroes until a sector, dd should write to all sectors, but never finished writing to all sectors. I watching the "status=progress" it stopping at like 20XX MB written.

Tried modified version of dd called dcfldd: same trouble.

fdisk & mkfs.fat: It seems doing his job well, but not fixing filesystem.

Gparted crashes while making new partition table & file system.

fsck & badblocks not working.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? As they say "It's dead, Jim". The VendorID/ProductID... are from the micro-controller, and you'll get them even if the flash memory chip is faulty. This thing is cheap and need to be trusted, no point trying to revive it.

Comment: Determine what controller and memory chip is used in your flash drive. Find controller vendor software for low-level init (or any generic software, ChipGenius for example) and try to restore your flash drive.

Comment: "_it stopping_" - what's the error?

Comment: "_mkfs.fat: It seems doing his job well, but not fixing filesystem_" - this won't "_fix_" a filesystem, but rather create a new one...

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like (part of) the flash RAM on the stick is broken.
Throw it away.
There is no way to fix that problem.

Comment: *There is no way to fix that problem.* I have recovered 4 flash drives with similar problems during last 1.5 years using the method described in a comment to the question. Of course, I inform their owners that reliability of recovered flash is close to zero. But I know that at least 2 of them are safe at present.

Comment: @akina in my experience ‘repairing’ such issues is very unreliable. I would not trust my data to such a flash-drive ever again. Flash media is just too cheap and my data too valuable to take the risk.

Comment: *I would not trust my data to such a flash-drive ever again.* I woud not trust my data to any flash drive at all - its reliability is similar to diskette's one. I use them only like a temporary media to transfer data from one location to another when cloud storage is unavailable. When I need in trusted storage I use external HDD.

Comment: @Akina, I have few 3.5" diskettes written in 1988, on Atari ST1040, , and they still read fine... go figure..

Comment: @AliChen Say "All 3.5" diskettes written on Atari ST1040 in 1988 still read fine" ... will you?

Comment: @Akina, I also have a dozen of HDDs that either failed to spin due to head stuck somewhere to surface, or start-stop spinning endlessly, or otherwise dead or semi-dead. How does it make them as "trusted storage"?

Comment: @AliChen Well, let's say "more trusted".